How to import npm in Glitch.com
I am trying to import { decode } from "@here/flexpolyline" which does not run in script.js.
I created a webpack.config.js and created a bundle.js to import the npm but it's still not working.
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/google-maps-powerapps-iframe
Any help is appreciated.
